# SVG Image does not display the correct colors

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, svg

I'm quite new to displaying of SVG in aspx. Here's the short story of my issue.

The application that I am doing uploads an svg image then stores it in the database and then displays it. However, the problem lies when I display the svg.

I tried to display the svg image in this manner:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal output as HtmlTextWriter)
' some code
dim bytes() as Byte = SomeMethodThatRetrievesTheBytes()
Dim sr As New StreamReader(New MemoryStream(bytes))
Dim imageData as String = sr.ReadToEnd()

output.Write(svgData)

End Sub
```

But, the color of the display is incorrect. Here is the sample svg code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

This is the image I get.

[image]

Is there any way which I can fix this?

Comment: How are you displaying the image on the page?  Is it included as an `<img>`, or some other way?  If not an `img`, are you sure there is no CSS that is affecting the fill colour?

Comment: There is no `<img>` tag that was used because I posted directly the svg code while it is rendering. As for the CSS, I checked it and there is nothing that affects the image itself.